# nginx ignores location definitions using regular expressions

Tags: nginx

I got the following domain configuration on my nginx server (nginx 1.2.1):

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    location ~ /content/(.*)\.(txt|md) {
        return 301 /error;
    }

    location ~ /tpl/(.*) {
        return 301 /error;
    }

    location ~ /sys/(.*) {
        return 301 /error;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I want to disallow access to all `.txt`/`.md` files in my `content` directory as well as every access to my `/tpl` and `/sys` directories. But, nginx seems to ignore each one of these rules.

So I tried something different, i.e.:

```
location ^~ /templates {
    return 404;
}
```

As this works, I guess there's a precedence-problem. Does anybody know how the apply all 3 rules?

Thanks!

— Max

Comment: try full URL instead of relative `/error`

Comment: Thanks, I replaced it with "return 301 $scheme://$host/error;" and it works, but only SOMETIMES. This is really weird.

- example.com/content/test.txt > WORKS
- example.com/tpl/header.php > DOESN'T WORK
- example.com/core/test.php > DOESN'T WORK

Comment: by doesn't work you mean 404? 500? wrong page?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the files are accessible. For example `example.com/tpl/header.php` still shows the PHP output of header.php.

Comment: I think you could just remove the regex and use `location /tpl` by default it should include all subfolders